# Can we show Quick Launch menu in SharePoint 2019 (communication site) modern page like classic site?

Tags: modern-experience, 2019, quick-launch, menu

I am using the SharePoint server 2019 communication site (modern UI on-prem). I want to show a Quick Launch menu (Current Navigation) on the left side like a classic site. Is it possible to show the Quick Launch menu on the left side? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Modern Communication template doesn't have left navigation. In communication site template Top Navigation is referring Quick Launch menu. If you want Left Navigation then you have to use Team Site Template which has left navigation by default.